# push object in a class array with ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

Hi i tried alot to push the variables which are in initialize to a class array but it always give error like this 'uninitialized class variable @@books in Object (NameError)'
code is here:

```
class Library
    @@books = Array.new
    @@books = []
    attr_reader :bookName, :author
    def initialize(bookName,author)
        @bookName = bookName
        @author = author
        
        @@books.push(self)
    end
    def countbooks
        $count = 0
        @@books.each do |b|
             count += 1
    end
end
```

i used `@@books.push(self)` to take all variables of object to an array but it did not work.

Comment: Tip: Use `[]` instead of `Array.new`. You use both here, bizarrely. Only the second one "counts".

Comment: Note: Ruby is a case-sensitive language and capital letters have specific meaning in terms of syntax. Variables and method names should be lower-case letters. Capitals indicate constants of the form  `ClassName` or `CONSTANT_NAME`.

Comment: Can't reproduce when using this code and `l = Library.new('Hello', 'World')`. If you have a use-case that fails, please include it.

Comment: @tadman i used [] instead of Array.new but it still gives the same error.

Comment: A) How do you get the error? B) What version of Ruby are you using?

Comment: when i want to count the books in library by the code i edited my question i give this error 'odev1.rb:13:in `<main>': uninitialized class variable @@books in Object (NameError)'

Comment: i am using 2.7.2 version of Ruby

Comment: You don’t need to write a method to count the elements of an array!

Comment: Tip: Do not use global variables. `$` = global.

Comment: `@@books.length` is your count.

Comment: This code would make more sense if you had `class Book` which you could put into another class called `Library` which represents a collection of books. As in `l = Library.new` and then `l << Book.new(...)` where you write `def <<` to add books. Doing things like `Library.new('Some Book', 'Some Author')` seems weird, as that's describing a book, not a library.

Comment: so can i add new books by using loop at any method to this `@@books` array? like `@@books.each do |b|
        b.bookname=gets.to_i
        b.author=gets.to_s'

Comment: No. That will replace any entries that already exist. Why `to_i` on the name? Are all your books like 412 or 9999? `each` iterates over *existing* content, it does not *make* entries.

Comment: Ok, got it. No, i should use `to_s` instead of `to_i`.

Comment: You only need `.to_s` to convert *to* a string. If it's already one, that doesn't do anything. `gets` returns a string, but it might have a newline, so the convention is `gets.chomp` to remove that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DISCLAIMER: I haven't used Ruby for some time, so some of my knowledge might be outdated. Feel free to correct me.

There are multiple problems with your code. Let's get the code you provided into some sort of running state.

First of all, you are missing an ***end*** in your provided code within the countbooks method. It needs an end to close the loop. Second, you can use either Array.new or [] as they both create an empty array, but if you use both you just overwrite the first new, empty array.

If you now initialize an instance of your new class and call the method countbooks, you will receive an error because you don't access your global variable ***$count***, but ***count*** instead, which has never been initialized. If you fix this, you can now just call the countbooks method and then a puts($count) and you get the current number.

However, global variables are generally bad practices, so you should avoid them. Remove the $ sign and add a ***return count*** after the loop ends, and we kind of replicated the ***Array.length*** method, just a lot slower :)

This should yield the following code:

```
class Library
    @@books = []
    attr_reader :bookName, :author
    def initialize(bookName,author)
        @bookName = bookName
        @author = author
        
        @@books.push(self)
    end
    def countbooks
        count = 0
        @@books.each do |b|
             count += 1
        end
        return count
    end
end
```

The code should now be executable, but there is a big problem.

**The class variable @@books:**
You now have a single array for the whole class. That means, if we create a new instance of the class Library, the array will be shared across all of them.

```
x = Library.new("title","bintree")
y = Library.new("title2","bintree2")
puts(x.countbooks)
puts(y.bookName)
```

x.countsbooks will return 2 and you only push new entries to the array if you create a new instance of Library.

From your question, I understand that you now try to call @@books outside of the class. This will not work. It only exists in the Library class. You can not use the attr accessors to gain access, either.

You probably should read more on classes, instances, and especially the different variable types. These links helped me to answer your question:

[More about classes, instances, and a bit about variables](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/faq/8/)

[More about arrays](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Array.html)

Here is an example of how the code could look like if we ignore build-in functions such as Array.length to implement our own counter and avoid class (@@) and global ($) variables. You can gain access to the ***@books*** if you now add ***attr_reader :books***, but it would be better to write a method instead.

```
class LibraryBTD
    def initialize
        @books = Array.new
        @counter = 0
    end
    
    def addBook(title,author)
        @books.push([title,author])
        @counter += 1
    end
    
    def listAllBooks
        puts("There are currently " + @counter.to_s + " books in the library.")
        @books.each do |book|
            title = book[0]
            author = book[1]
            puts("Title: " + title + " | Author: " + author)
        end
    end
end
```

If we now create a new instance of LibraryBTD and add 2 books, we can list them with listAllBooks:

```
a = LibraryBTD.new
a.addBook("MyBook1","BTD")
a.addBook("MyBook2","BTD")
a.listAllBooks
```

This should output the following in the console:

> There are currently 2 books in the library.

> Title: MyBook1 | Author: BTD

> Title: MyBook2 | Author: BTD

However, if we create a new instance, the list will be empty, because ***@books*** is only an instance variable.

```
b = LibraryBTD.new
b.listAllBooks
```

> There are currently 0 books in the library.